# Ubuntu 20.04 installation

Tags: nvidia, 20.04

Ubuntu 20.04 fails to install when option to to use Nvidia Proprietary Drivers is selected. Please advise any ideas on a fix ? This seems to exclude Nvidia GEForce etal from the 20.04 release?

Comment: Simply don't select to install the driver from the installer. You can install it later from a proper boot.

Comment: Yes 1) I retried 20.04 installation,result OK.2) loaded the correct Nvidia-driver-455-distro,appeared OK. 3) triedagain  to load the Nvidia Cuda tool kit and same broken package report again... Any thoughts appreciated!